# C# Threading Ram Usage

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating a web page flooder to test some security on my servers.
I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url;
    int times;
    Console.WriteLine("Inserisci l'indirizzo(pagina specifica) da floodare");
    url = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Quante volte?");
    times = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 350;
    var block = new System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ActionBlock<int>(async i =>
    {
        try
        {
            await Work(i, url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }, new System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 350 });

    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        block.Post(i);
    }
    block.Complete();

    Task.WaitAll(block.Completion);
}
private static async Task<bool> Work(int i, string url)
{
    if (i % 1000 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    new WebClient().UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());

    //await Task.Delay(1);
    return true;
}
}
```

It does its job just fine but it has one problem. If i set the number of requests really high(like 200 thousands or more) it uses a LOT of ram. At 1.3 millions requests it uses 3.3gb of ram. I tried to dispose everything, to free ram in any way but it seems that the block variable stores every thread untill it finishes. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you not awaiting `UploadValuesTaskAsync` inside `Work()`? Did you try to dispose the `WebClient`?

Comment: yes i tried. I do not want to wait for it to be completed, i just want to run it, i don't care about the result

Comment: @LifeRewind, did you try memory profiler? What objects are not collected by GC?

Comment: I tried memory profiler but i do not know how to use it well. I didn't find where i could see that

Comment: anyway i think the block variable is causing all this

Comment: _"At 1.3 millions requests it uses 3.3gb of ram"_ -- that's "only" about 3KB per request. That doesn't sound unreasonable to me, especially if one assumes that most of that overhead is a buffer for the I/O. Maybe using an API that keeps all of your requests in memory until you're done isn't the best approach. What else have you tried?

Comment: @LifeRewind, it's really simple task. You can use [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) and [here is video of its using](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCh4ndExogs)

Comment: I don't know what else to try. I need parallelism and this is what i came out with. You have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In `Work` you don't wait for the IO to complete. This makes `Work` complete extremely quickly. This effectively disables the rate limiting that you wanted (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 350`).

Work is started much faster than it is completed. That's why work items accumulate and consume memory.

Wait for the IO to complete.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found. You're using WebClient, but don't dispose it.
[image: WebClient leaks]

Work method should be something like this:

```
private static async Task<bool> Work(int i, string url)
{
    if (i % 1000 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    // Must dispose to avoid leaks
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        await wc.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());
    }
    //await Task.Delay(1);
    return true;
}
```

**Updated**
I've used [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) and asynchronous method [BeginGetResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) to solve your problem. Full code is https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZecQku:

```
namespace HttpWebRequest_HighIntesive
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading;

    class ThreadParam
    {
        public int RequestsCount { get; private set; }
        public CountdownEvent CountdownEvent { get; private set; }
        public ThreadParam(int requestsCount, CountdownEvent countdownEvent)
        {
            RequestsCount = requestsCount;
            CountdownEvent = countdownEvent;
        }
    }
    class FinistRequestParam
    {
        public CountdownEvent CountdownEvent { get; private set; }
        public HttpWebRequest HttpWebRequest { get; private set; }
        public FinistRequestParam(CountdownEvent countdownEvent, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
        {
            CountdownEvent = countdownEvent;
            HttpWebRequest = httpWebRequest;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static Uri _uri;
        static volatile int _numberOfFinishedRequests;
        static double _prevMemoryMb = 0;

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numOfRequests;
            Console.Write("Enter URL(full format, for example, http://google.ru): ");
            var url = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out _uri)){
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid URL. Exiting"); return -1;
            }
            Console.Write("Enter number of requests: ");
            numOfRequests = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("");
            DoParallelRequests(numOfRequests);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished. Press 'Enter' to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
        private static void DoParallelRequests(int numOfRequests)
        {
            // Play with DefaultConnectionLimit
            // Increasing this value will increase speed, but also increase memory consumption
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 350;
            Console.WriteLine("DefaultConnectionLimit: {0}", System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);
            int threadCnt = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Console.WriteLine("Num of threads which creates HttpWebRequest: {0}", threadCnt);
            // Initialize CountDownEvent with numOfRequests
            CountdownEvent countDownOnTimes = new CountdownEvent(numOfRequests);
            // Create timer for statistics
            using (var timer = new Timer(TimerStatisticHanlder, Stopwatch.StartNew(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
            {
                // Create thread array
                Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCnt];
                // Initialize each thread and start it
                for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
                {
                    threads[i] = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
                    // HACK Hope numOfRequests % threadCnt == 0 (evenly divisible)
                    // Start thread
                    threads[i].Start(new ThreadParam(numOfRequests / threadCnt, countDownOnTimes));
                }
                // Will wait untill all request processed
                countDownOnTimes.Wait();
            }
        }
        static void TimerStatisticHanlder(object obj)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = obj as Stopwatch;
            // Calculate average speed
            var aveageSpeed = Math.Round(_numberOfFinishedRequests / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 2);
            // Get total memory
            var totalMemoryMb = Math.Round((double)GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024 / 1024);
            // Calculate memory delta
            var memoryDeltaMb = totalMemoryMb - _prevMemoryMb;
            // Print out statistics
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Processed requests: {1}, Average speed: {2} requests per/s, Used memory: {3} Mbytes, Memory delta: {4}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), _numberOfFinishedRequests, aveageSpeed, totalMemoryMb, memoryDeltaMb);
            // Store total memory for delta calculation
            _prevMemoryMb = totalMemoryMb;
        }
        private static void ThreadMethod(object state)
        {
            var threadParam = state as ThreadParam;
            for (int i = 0; i <= threadParam.RequestsCount; i++)
            {
                // Create HttpWebRequest
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
                // Start it asynchronous
                request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), new FinistRequestParam(threadParam.CountdownEvent, request));
            }
        }
        private static void FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var reqParam = result.AsyncState as FinistRequestParam;
            var request = reqParam.HttpWebRequest;
            try
            {
                // Just end response
                HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
                // Release all resources
                response.GetResponseStream().Dispose();
                response.Close();
                (request as IDisposable).Dispose();
            }
            catch { } // Don't care about exceptions

            // Mark yet another request finished
            reqParam.CountdownEvent.Signal();
            // Increment total number of finished requests
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _numberOfFinishedRequests);
        }
    }
}
```

Screen of test app:
[image: Scree of test app]

Comment: this is ok but if you put an await, it loses the main goal, to flood. But if I take the awat away, even using your code. it uses a lot of ram. I think the problem is in the way i call the function. I think that the block variable stores everything untill it is finished. Do you have any suggestion?